# How can I get a web site's favicon?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, favicon

I've created a small app that is basically just a favourites that sits in my system tray so that I can open often-used sites/folders/files from the same place. Getting the default icons from my system for known file types isn't terribly complicated, but I don't know how to get the favicon from a website. (SO has the grey->orange stack icon in the address bar for instance)

Does anyone know how I might go about that?

Comment: I'm not sure how easy (or possible) it would be to automate the loading/parsing of this page, but it seems to have everything: [Favicon-Checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker#.XSI6p6KtiuP). At the very least, you can use it as a reference/check.

Comment: You could just use the [Statvoo Favicon API](https://favicons.statvoo.com), that'd be pretty quick and painless.

Comment: [Favicon Kit](https://faviconkit.com/?ref=stackoverflow) lets you get & embed favicons like regular images, in [sizes much larger than 16 pixels](https://api.faviconkit.com/stackoverflow.com/144), if available. (Disclosure: I’m the author)

Answer (score 377, accepted):

You'll want to tackle this a few ways:

1. Look for the `favicon.ico` at the root of the domain

   `www.domain.com/favicon.ico`
2. Look for a `<link>` tag with the `rel="shortcut icon"` attribute

   `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`
3. Look for a `<link>` tag with the `rel="icon"` attribute

   `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />`

The latter two will usually yield a higher quality image.

---

Just to cover all of the bases, there are device specific icon files that might yield higher quality images since these devices usually have larger icons on the device than a browser would need:

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch.png" />`

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/touch.png" />`

---

And to download the icon without caring what the icon is you can use a utility like http://www.google.com/s2/favicons which will do all of the heavy lifting:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.DownloadFile(
    @"http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com",
    "stackoverflow.com.ico");
```

Comment: does GetFavIcon still work? when I run your example I get a 400 error

Comment: looks like Google has a similar service now: http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=stackoverflow.com

Comment: if anyone wants an alternative to Google, DuckDuckGo has another solution: http://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip2/www.stackoverflow.com.ico

Comment: Thanks so much, option 1 worked for me, after searching for 20 minutes!

Comment: @hunter `google.com/s2/favicons` it is an icon with 16x16 it is terrible icon do you know where to take larger icon ?

Comment: @JoseSerodio - The link you provided works as shown, but how do you format the domain you're checking? I mean the part after "/ip2/".

Comment: @KevinFegan if the website is "eldiario.es" just https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip2/eldiario.es.ico ... just after /ip2/ add the website and then ".ico"

Comment: @JoseSerodio - Well... that was the first thing I tried, but for the domain I was checking, I just got a "dim/dull" image of a right pointing arrow (greater-than) inside a circle-inside a square. [It looked like this](https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip2/.ico), but I checked to make sure I had "domain.com.ico" spelled correctly. Now, by the wonders of the internet, it's working correctly... go figure =) so, Nevermind.

Comment: 2 & 3 amount to the same: finding `<link>` with `icon` within whitespace-separated keywords.  I recommend not using any 3rd-party *service*, even Google, as it could be discontinued at any moment.  By all means use a 3rd-party *library* to do the scraping and caching of results.  You must also hotlink (not copy) the image to avoid copyright infringement.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi add the parameter `&sz=:size` where `:size` is the size in px, e.g. [`https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=32&domain_url=stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=32&domain_url=stackoverflow.com)

Comment: the favicon.ico works nice, you just need to be sure to ba at website root :
cut the path from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119041/how-can-i-get-a-web-sites-favicon to https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico.
You'll need a little extension or helper method for that. the use :
using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(favIcoPath), localPath);
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                        return path.ToBitmapImage();
                }

Comment: @JoseSerodio How to ommit placeholder icon for unknown domain, so I could try to fetch from another service in "onerror" listener?

Comment: @AryanTYB Are there public documentation about which parameters can be used?

Answer (score 63):

**Updated 2020**

Here are three services you can use in 2020 onwards

```
<img height="16" width="16" src='https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip3/www.google.com.ico' />

<img height="16" width="16" src='http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.com' />

<img height="16" width="16" src='https://api.statvoo.com/favicon/google.com' />
```

Comment: grabicon.com is now paid service starting from $9/mo

Comment: Another one: http://favicon.allesedv.com/ <img width="144" height="144" src="//f3.allesedv.com/144/www.stackoverflow.com" />

Comment: This service no-longer works, you can use https://api.statvoo.com/favicon/?url=stackoverflow.com. I've used it for a couple of years and it's never let me down.

Comment: Thanks @AO_, im actually using duckduckgo these days, Ive updated my answer

Comment: @AO_ then stavoo api is just a wrapper to the google service

Comment: @saintvixalien I believe this has recently changed for people who don't initialise with an API key, as the servers were getting pounded ;) I use the primary service with an API key and get responses directly without the wrapper. I did test without an API key and it redirects to Google's service as you said..

Comment: @MartinSeitl `allesedv` is no longer online, you can't use that any more.  Best I think is to scrape the HTML `head` for `<link rel="icon">` and hotlink and cache the best result.

Comment: @jake thx 4 your comment! favicon.allesedv.com is online again.

Comment: How to ommit placeholder icon for unknown domain, so I could try next service in "onerror" listener?

Comment: api.statvoo.com seems to just redirect to Google's S2 service.

Answer (score 19):

You can use Google S2 Converter.

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com

Source: http://www.labnol.org/internet/get-favicon-image-of-websites-with-google/4404/

Comment: Yep this is what I do. For my tampermonkey scripts, I just change `domain=` (e.g. https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=doodstream.com)

Answer (score 17):

This question is the first google search result I got when I keep searching for website favicon API. So I think it'll be still helpful in the future.

[https://icon.horse/icon/[url.hostname]](https://icon.horse/icon/%5Burl.hostname%5D) will give you a better site icon.

https://icon.horse/icon/stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 10):

You can do it **without programming** in 3 steps:

  1. Just open the web site, right-click and select
  **"view source"**
  to open the HTML code of that site. Then in the text editor search for
  **"favicon"**
  - it will direct you to something looking like
  > `<link rel="icon" href='/SOMERELATIVEPATH/favicon.ico' type="image/x-icon" />`
  Take the string in `href` and append it to the web site's base URL (let's assume it is `"http://WEBSITE/"`), so it looks like
  > `http://WEBSITE/SOMERELATIVEPATH/favicon.ico`
  which is the absolute path to the favicon. If you didn't find it this way, it can be as well in the root in which case the URL is `http://WEBSITE/favicon.ico`.

  2. Take the URL you determined and insert it into the
  **href**
  -Parameter of the following code:
  ```
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Capture Favicon</title>   
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href='http://WEBSITE/SOMERELATIVEPATH/favicon.ico' alt="Favicon"/>Favicon</a> 
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

  3. Save this HTML code locally (e.g. on your desktop) as
  **GetFavicon.html**
  and then double-click on it to open it. It will display only a link named
  **Favicon**
  . Right-click on this link and select
  **"Save target as..."**
  to save the Favicon on your local PC - and you're done!

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to look for is /favicon.ico in the site root; something like WebClient.DownloadFile() should do fine. However, you can also set the icon in metadata - for SO this is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"
   href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

and note that alternative icons might be available; the "touch" one tends to be bigger and higher res, for example:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"
   href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

so you would parse that in either the HTML Agility Pack or XmlDocument (if xhtml) and use WebClient.DownloadFile()

Here's some code I've used to obtain this via the agility pack:

```
var favicon = "/favicon.ico";
var el=root.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/link[@rel='shortcut icon' and @href]");
if (el != null) favicon = el.Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Note the icon is theirs, not yours.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I appreciate the example. Wrt the images, I don't intend to modify them or use them for anything other than icons in the context menu beside the shortcut's label.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good practice to minimize the number of requests each page needs.
So if you need several icons, yandex can do a sprite of favicons in one query.
Here is an example
http://favicon.yandex.net/favicon/google.com/stackoverflow.com/yandex.net/

Answer (score 7):

In 2020, using duckduckgo.com's service from the CLI

```
curl -v https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip2/<website>.ico > favicon.ico
```

Example

```
curl -v https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip2/www.cdc.gov.ico > favicon.ico
```

Comment: Worked great for me.

Answer (score 7):

Combining answers from my own research and couple of other resources below.

There are a couple of ways to achieve depending on your requirement. And some are more reliable than the others

1. get a url to embed the favicon somewhere else:

   - Google API

     - **Example**: http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com
     - in the above url, you can replace `domain=google.com` with `domain=<other_website_domain>`
   - [Clearbit Logo](https://clearbit.com/logo)

     - **Example**: https://logo.clearbit.com/google.com
     - you can use this link directly and you don't have to sign-up to use this
   - [Favicon Grabber](https://favicongrabber.com/)

     - this fetches the url from the main website which you can use without depending on other tools
   - [Favicon Kit](https://faviconkit.com/)

     - **Example**: https://organisational-cyan-rooster.faviconkit.com/google.com/144
     - you'll need to sign-up for an account - which will let you manage links
2. fetch multiple website favicons together

   - favicon.yandex.net

     - **Example**: http://favicon.yandex.net/favicon/google.com/stackoverflow.com/yandex.net/
     - reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35328921/6908282
3. other alternatives

   - [Browser specific tool](https://superuser.com/a/1443114/863212)

     - copy and open this url in a new tab in a chrome/edge browser
       `chrome://favicon/https://google.com`
       `edge://favicon/https://google.com`
   - [domain favico.ico url](https://superuser.com/a/157939/863212)

     - some or a lot of the websites have their favicon typically hosted in their root domain like https://google.com/favicon.ico
   - [Manual Approach](https://superuser.com/a/544323/863212) (not always reliable)

     - Inspect any website by **Right-Click > Inspect** and search (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) for `shortcut icon` and copy the url if you find it.
   - [RealFaviconGenerator - Favicon Checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker)

     - this analyses the website and provides you with results if icon is valid and if you can find it reliably
     - **Example**: https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?protocol=http&site=google.com

Answer (score 6):

You can get the favicon URL from the website's HTML.

Here is the `favicon` element:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/someimage.png" />
```

You should use a regular expression here. If no tag found, look for `favicon.ico` in the site root directory. If nothing found, the site does not have a favicon.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
HttpWebRequest w = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico");

w.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

HttpWebResponse r = (HttpWebResponse)w.GetResponse();

System.Drawing.Image ico;
using (Stream s = r.GetResponseStream())
{
    ico = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
}

ico.Save("favicon.ico");
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we can't get the favicon image with the purposed solution as some websites use .png or other image extensions. Here is the working solution.

1. Open your website with a **firefox browser**.
2. Right-click on the website and click the **"View page info"** option from the list.
3. It will open up a dialog and click on the **"Media"** tab.
4. In that tab you will see all the images including favicon.
5. Select the favicon.ico image or click through the images to see which image is used as favicon. Some websites use .png images as well.
6. Then click on the **"Save As"** button and you should be good to go.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but for completeness: it is difficult to get even close to fetching 90% all favicons.

A while ago I wrote [a WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favicons) which attempts to get closer to 100%.

This is how it works:

1. It starts by searching existing favicon repositories such as Google favicons and GetFavicons for the favicon.
2. If none of them returns an icon, the plugin attempts to get the icon itself. This involves traversing several pages on the domain.
3. The plugin then inspects the physical image file, because on some servers files get returned with the incorrect mime types.

The code is still not perfect because in the details you will find many weird situations: people have wrongly coded paths, e.g. `img/favicon.ico` where `img` is not in the root, duplicate headers in HTML output, different server responses from the head and body etc.

The core of the fetching part [is here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-favicons/trunk/includes/server/class-http.php) so you can reverse-engineer it, but be aware that validating the response should be done (checking image filetype, mime etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The `SHGetFileInfo` (Check [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) for the signature) lets you retrieve a small or large icon, just as if you were dealing with a file/folder/Shell item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Getfv.co](http://getfavicon.appspot.com/) :

> To retrieve a favicon you can hotlink it at... http://g.etfv.co/[URL]

Example for this page : http://g.etfv.co/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119041/how-can-i-get-a-web-sites-favicon

Download content and let's go !

Edit :

Getfv.co and fvicon.com look dead. If you want I found a non free alternative : [grabicon.com](https://grabicon.com/).

Comment: Link dead, Error: Not Found

Comment: @tttony Indeed. fvicon.com looks dead too. I will edit my comment with paid content. if you find a working free link, please share it!

Answer (score 0):

http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=http://stackoverflow.com gives you favicon analysis stating which favicons are present in what size. You can process the page information to see which is the best quality favicon, and append it's filename to the URL to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```
var favicon = $("link[rel='shortcut icon']").attr("href") ||
              $("link[rel='icon']").attr("href") || "";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using the network tab in the developer tools of your browser:**

1.) clear your cache

2.) open developer tools in your browser (F12) and click over to the network tab so requests are recorded

3.) visit the website

4.) in the search bar above the network requests, search for "favicon"

You should see the requests the browser made to retrieve the favicon images for that website. Alternatively, you can filter requests by type. In this case, choose "image" requests.

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

This simply worked for me (see the example below and the link to original answer).

1. Enter the domain name like https://superuser.com/(must end with '/')
2. Add favicon.ico to the end like - https://superuser.com/favicon.ico

Then you can save as from there. I found this answer here:
https://superuser.com/a/157939/365012